# Why do I get different query plans in SQLite3 for the same query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database that is updated and queried three different ways:

- The native Python 3.2 SQLite3 module
- DBVisualizer's JDBC for SQLite
- The sqlite3 executable

I have the same query run on all three:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT DISTINCT
method.method

FROM combination

INNER JOIN result
ON result.combination_key = combination.combination_key

INNER JOIN datalog AS datalog1
ON datalog1.datalog_key = combination.datalog_key1

INNER JOIN datalog AS datalog2
ON datalog2.datalog_key = combination.datalog_key2

INNER JOIN method
ON method.method_key = result.method_key

WHERE
datalog1.lot = 'datalog_name1' AND datalog2.lot = 'datalog_name2'
```

And yet I get three different results.

Python:

```
0   0   4   SCAN TABLE method USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_method_1 (~5 rows)
0   1   0   SCAN TABLE combination (~1838311 rows)
0   2   1   SEARCH TABLE result USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_result_1 (combination_key=? AND method_key=?) (~1 rows)
0   3   2   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0   4   3   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
```

DBVisualizer (**EDIT**: I've just updated the Xerial sqlite jdbc from 3.7 to 3.8, now the results are identical to sqlite.exe. Looks like all of these may be due to driver differences...):

```
0   0   4   SCAN TABLE method USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_method_1
0   1   2   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog1 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_datalog_1 (ANY(program) AND lot=?)
0   2   0   SEARCH TABLE combination USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_combination_1 (datalog_key1=?)
0   3   1   SEARCH TABLE result USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_result_1 (combination_key=? AND method_key=?)
0   4   3   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

sqlite.exe:

```
0   0   4   SCAN TABLE method USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_method_1
0   1   2   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog1 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_datalog_1 (ANY(program) AND lot=?)
0   2   0   SEARCH TABLE combination USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_combination_1 (datalog_key1=?)
0   3   1   SEARCH TABLE result USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_result_1 (combination_key=? AND method_key=?)
0   4   3   SEARCH TABLE datalog AS datalog2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

Question 1: Why are the query plans different?

Question 2: If I need to optimize a query, must I depend upon the query plan generated by the method that I'm using to run the query? In other words, do I need to tune my queries individually for each of these?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the answer: all of the drivers for these were from different versions of sqlite3.

The executable, sqlite.exe, was up to date.

DBVisualizer was upgraded by downloading the latest Xerial sqlite jdbc JAR driver and pointing DBVis at it.

Python was upgraded by downloading the latest DLLs from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and manually replacing sqlite.dll in my Python directory.

All seem to be running the same now.

Comment: Man I love it when I find an answer with little votes and views, but it exactly solves my problem. Thank you for this :) The internet and people are great :)